# How do I prevent future commit date/time in git (server-/origin-side)

Tags: git, datetime, githooks

If one of the involved developers has a **wrong systemclock, his commits may have the wrong time and date within them**. How can I prevent those commits to be accepted (**pre receive hook?**) in the "origin"-repo?

This might not be a problem for the integrity because future commits reference those commits and they might have the correct time. So one can say the commits must have been made before that time. But if I don't want *incorrect* commits in general?

It should be very easy but I could not find any resource where this was discussed. It should be similar to checking the author corresponds to the account that is allowed to push to that origin/server/-repo.

Comment: The commit time has nothing to do with when it was pushed to the server. I could make a commit two years ago, rebase it on top of today's HEAD, and push it. What is important is when it enters into the common project history (i.e. when it was pushed).

Comment: you can even make a new commit on top of HEAD with ANY datetime at all and push that, I know that already. But I'm asking about preventing those commits from being accepted when pushed (checked through the server side=>maybe in pre receive hook). I'm also not asking if this is desirable or practicable but information on additional topics can always be relevant)

Comment: actually, some tools do use the commit time for ordering, so it's better to have it properly ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`pre-receive`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks/server-side-hooks) hook. In the hook, you'd parse the output for each commit with

```
git show -s --format=%ci <SHA>
```

compare this to the output of `date` and act accordingly.

That said, I'll repeat what I said in the comments that this is not desirable in the git because the idea is precisely that people can work asynchronously and push to the server. What matters is the the order in which a commit became part of the common history, not when it was edited.